# Separate address for clients

Tags: hazelcast

I have a hz cluster with all of the members in the same network but the clients are in a different network.  The clients can connect to the members via a NAT'd address. Is there a way to get Hazelcast to pass out a separate IP address to clients.  I am looking for something like  that is applied only for clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [Advanced Network Configuration](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0/manual/html-single/index.html#advanced-network-configuration). The feature is available since Hazelcast 3.12. The code sample at https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/network-configuration/advanced-network-configuration demonstrates how to configure your cluster members for such a scenario. The key point is that you should define the NAT'd member address as the `publicAddress` of your client protocol endpoint configuration.